# How to pull AIP Scanner's result from Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-information-protection

I was wondering if there is an endpoint to pull the results once AIP scanner has finished its job?

I have browsed graph explorer extensively on the Azure and couldn't find it. I am aware they have an SDK and a power-shell app for the said scanner, but I was wondering if it can be done via REST or SDK?

Thank you

Comment: As far as I am aware there is nothing available for this right now out of the box. You can use the REST endpoint to start the scan, but it doesn't wait until the scan is complete to respond, and the results are ultimately posted to the Azure Portal. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/get-compliance-data

You can view results under %localappdata%MicrosoftMSIPScannerReports

Comment: You can use Microsoft Graph to evaluate the information protection classification results. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/informationprotectionlabel-evaluateclassificationresults?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http